# JQueryUI Slider - 3 Labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am working on a project that requires the user to select a hidden value from -10<=>10

I like the look and function of the JQueryUI widgets, and the increment slider would work if.... I can place 3 labels.

OptionA..................Neutral.....................OptionB

Their is a well-formed JSFiddle that has formatted numbers or ticks for each increment spot.  I would really just like it to have the 3 as illustrated above.

http://jsfiddle.net/9y501okz/

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 4,
    min: 1,
    max: 7,
    step: 1
})
    .each(function () {
        //
        // Add labels to slider whose values 
        // are specified by min, max and whose
        // step is set to 1
        //
        // Get the options for this slider
        var opt = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;
        // Get the number of possible values
        var vals = opt.max - opt.min;
        // Space out values
        for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i++) {
            var el = $('<label>' + (i + 1) + '</label>').css('left', (i / vals * 100) + '%');
            $("#slider").append(el);
        }
    });

#slider label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* below is not necessary, just for style */
#slider {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is easily edited to achieve your desired results.

Change your slider initialization to use the following options:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value: 2,
    min: 1,
    max: 3,
    step: 1
})
```

Your labels can be edited by adding a simple switch inside your loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i++) {
  var text = "";
  switch (i) {
      case 0:
          text = "OptionA";
          break;
      case 1:
          text = "Neutral";
          break;
      case 2:
          text = "OptionB";
          break;
  }
  var el = $('<label>'+text+'</label>').css('left',(i/vals*100)+'%');

  $( "#slider" ).append(el);

}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/az5qfun9/)

Comment: That would be fine, but I need to have a 20pt range from -10 to +10, with a starting value of 0.

Comment: I have the beginning of a solution. I replaced the loop with three appends. Left, center, and right. It is very close.